# Why does TypeTag not work for return types?

Tags: scala, scala-2.10

It seems that `TypeTags` only work for type parameters that are used in the parameters of the called method, and not the return type:

```
scala> :paste
// Entering paste mode (ctrl-D to finish)

import scala.reflect.runtime.universe._

object Test {
  def withParam[T: TypeTag](v: T): T = {
    println(typeOf[T])
    0.asInstanceOf[T]
  }

  def justReturn[T: TypeTag](): T = {
    println(typeOf[T])
    0.asInstanceOf[T]
  }
}

// Exiting paste mode, now interpreting.

import scala.reflect.runtime.universe._
defined module Test


scala> val i: Int = Test.withParam(17)
Int
i: Int = 0

scala> val j: Int = Test.justReturn()
Nothing
j: Int = 0
```

This is consistent with the behaviour of Manifest in 2.9, but is there any reason it can't be done, and is there any other way to achieve this effect?

Comment: What else could it possibly do?  That is, what _should_ `justReturn` return?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The type system starts with the most restrictive type (i.e. `Nothing`, of which there can be no instances; if there were it would be a godlike value able to stand in for anything and do anything).  The type is then widened as needed, but since the return is in contravariant position, there's never a reason to widen.  If you actually could return a `Nothing`, you'd be set in all situations.

You then subvert the type system by telling it that `0` is an instance of `Nothing`.  It's completely false, of course, but the compiler dutifully believes you, and you rescue the situation by assigning it to an `Int`, which is what it really was all along.  (It will also happily try to assign it to a `String` and you'll then get an exception at runtime because at that point it is nonsensical.)

In theory this could be done differently, but this is a pretty basic part of the type inference algorithm.

Comment: In fact, if you invoke the original `justReturn` with an explicit type parameter other than `Int` it is a compile-time error. Interestingly enough, if you give an explicit type parameter that is compatible with `Int` via "weak conformance," the error does come at runtime. E.g., `Test.justReturn[Byte]()` elicits `java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to java.lang.Byte`.

Comment: @RandallSchulz - I get `ClassCastExceptions` in all cases.  What version are you using?  (2.10.0 here.)

Comment: If this is the way the algorithm works then that makes sense. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

To expand on Rex Kerr's comment, there is nothing do drive inference of `T` in the `justReturn` case. If you supply a (suitable) type parameter, you get this:

```
scala> val j: Int = Test.justReturn[Int]()
Int
j: Int = 0
```

If you change `justReturn` to this:

```
def justReturn[T: TypeTag]() {
  println(typeOf[T])
}
```

... then you can do this:

```
scala> justReturn[String]()
String

scala> justReturn[java.io.File]()
java.io.File
```